# WCF mex and DISCO

Tags: wcf

Could you please explain what is the difference between  “mex” and DISCO?

Thanks

Lijo

Answer (score 3):

Disco is a kind of music that was popular in the 70's, mex is short for Mexican cuisine.  Sometimes you might see TexMex which is short for Mexican Texan hybrid cuisine.  The two terms are vastly unrelated.

In all seriousness, Mex is short for meta-data exchange. Put simply, it's the WSDL document that describes your service or the contract to the client or caller.  It describes the data and the functions supported by your service.  You can get a WSDL document by typing service?wsdl.   DISCO is short for Discovery.  It is a document that contains the location URL of the WSDL and of the service itself.